# Error PHP execute on boolean

Tags: php

ME SALE ESTE ERROR: ya he intentado de varias maneras solucionarlo pero nada, es una tabla pero agarro datos de dos tablas de bd
**Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function execute() on bool.
$stmt2->execute();**

```js
 <?php
                            $sql = "select id,accion,tipo from acciones order by id";
                            $stmt = $conexion->prepare($sql);
                            $stmt->execute();
                            $stmt->bind_result($id,$accion,$tipo);
                            while ($stmt->fetch()){
                            echo "<tr>";
                            echo "<td>$accion</td>";
                            if(strlen(trim($tipo)==0) echo"<td>No está</td>";
                            else {
                                $sql2 = "select tipo from accionestipo where id = $tipo";
                                $stmt2 = $conexion->prepare($sql2);
                                echo $sql2;
                                $stmt2->execute();
                                $stmt2->bind_result($accionestipo);
                                $stmt2->fetch();
                                $stmt2->close();
                                echo "<td>$accionestipo</td>";

                            }
                         }
                         ?>
```

```html
                            <table>
                            <tr>
                                <th>No.</th>
                                <th>Accion</th>
                                <th>Tipo</th>
                            </tr>
                 
                            </table>
```

Comment: Evidentemente `$conexion->prepare($sql2)` está devolviendo `false`. Después de esa línea hace un `echo $stmt2->error` a ver que devuelve. Estás seguro que `$tipo` tiene lo que esperás?

Comment: Me sale eso: Notice: Trying to get property 'error' of non-object

Comment: Si, tipo me devuelve un entero y si imprimo la sql2, el query si esta bien

Comment: Perdón, quise decir `$conexion->error`.

Comment: Con conexión sale este error: Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now

Answer (score 0):

Voy a darte un ejemplo simple tanto de conexión como de listado:

Conexión:

```
<?php
try {
$conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=NOMBRE', 'root', 'PASS');
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
}
catch(PDOException $e){
    echo "ERROR: " . $e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

Listado

```
<?php
$list = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM proyectos WHERE estado = '0' ORDER BY id DESC");
while ($row = $list->fetch()) {
?>

<p><?=$row['titulo'];?></p>

<?php
}
?>
```

Esta es una de manera de hacerlo, repito, es una manera, hay mas formas. De tener en cuenta la conexión cuando hagas este tipo de trabajo, porque de lo contrario tendras mas errores.

Espero haberte ayudaro!

Comment: En el código aparece el uso de `bind_result`, por lo que es posible que el OP esté usando `mysqli`. No tiene nada que ver con PDO.

Comment: Entiendo... no he notado ese detalle.... pido dsculpas!

Answer (score 0):

No necesitas hacer dos consultas, ya que la segunda consulta que realizas: **`select tipo from accionestipo where id = $tipo`** indica claramente que **hay una relación entre las dos tablas**, por lo tanto, puedes expresar dicha relación uniendo las tablas mediante un `JOIN`.

En este ejemplo te mostraré una unión del tipo `INNER JOIN` (hay otros tipos, si por ejemplo quieres mostrar como `NULL` las filas que no coincidan en una de las tablas puedes usar `LETF JOIN` o `RIGHT JOIN` según el caso... o más tipos de `JOIN`, pero eso no viene al caso ahora, lo digo para abrir esa ventana a los `JOIN` que te evitará estar repitiendo consultas sin necesidad).

En la consulta que se ejecuta se hace un `JOIN` entre las tablas asumiendo que la columna `tipo` de la tabla `acciones` sirve para relacionar las filas en `accionestipo` mediante la columna `id` de esa tabla.

Otra cosa es que no necesitas usar consultas preparadas para este caso, porque realmente no hay datos que vengan del exterior, por eso he usado `query`. Si de todos modos quieres usar consultas preparadas puedes adaptarlo.

He mejorado también el código HTML, poniendo ciertas cosas donde deberían ir (ponías las cabeceras de la tabla a posteriori por ejemplo), además, por claridad, he concatenado todo en una variable.

He añadido también un manejo de error, por si la consulta falla.

Prueba de este modo y dime si funciona en comentarios. Espero te sirva.

```
<?php
    $sql = "select a.id,a.accion,at.tipo 
                from acciones a 
                INNER JOIN  accionestipo at ON a.tipo=at.id 
                order by a.id";
    if ( $stmt = $conexion->query($sql) ) {
        $html="
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <th>No.</th>
                    <th>Accion</th>
                       <th>Tipo</th>
                </tr>";
        while ($row=$stmt->fetch_assoc()){
            $html.="<tr><td>$row[id]</td><td>$row[accion]</td><td>$row[tipo]</td></tr>";
        }
        $html.="</table>";
    } else {
        $html="Error en la consulta: {$conexion->error}";
    }
    echo $html;
?>
```